# Perl Net::FTPSSL, won't connect, timeout or throw errors

Tags: perl, sftp

I am trying to use perl's [Net::FTPSSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTPSSL) to connect to a host.  When I run the script, it hangs and eventually times out on my error logs, but not to the browser.  The problem seems to be when creating the new connection.  If I use Filezilla to connect, there is a pause/response warning that the host key is unknown.  When I 'ok' it in Filezilla, it passes a command "Trust new Hostkey: Once" and send the password and logs in.  If this is my problem, how do I send that 'ok'?  Here is my code - it hangs on the second line - before even getting to the username/password.

The code I'm using is:

```
use Net::FTPSSL;
$ftpobj = Net::FTPSSL -> new('host.com', Port => 21) or die "Can't open server.";
$ftpobj -> login("user","pass");
$ftpobj -> get ("file.csv");
$ftpobj -> quit;
```

Comment: Of course, I still played around with this and changed Encryption from default 'E' to 'I' + added a Croak=>1, which is give better errors and now I get: "Can't open tcp connection!"

So, obviously the 'I' (implicit) causes it to fail the connection, which makes me think the 'E' wants to connect.  Does this help any more?

Answer (score 1):

This might be intentional, but sftp is usually hosted on port 22, and you have port 21.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I left it at port 21 which is in most of the examples found with the pm information.  I actually tried 21 and 22 (which is what the host informed me to use).

Answer (score 0):

SFTP and FTPS are two completely different protocols:

- FTPS is FTP on top of SSL or TLS
- SFTP is a protocol for file transfer that runs on top of SSH